# While loop without expected behavior

Tags: python, while-loop

I am starting in Python. In the current code, A1 is "returned" infinitely, as if there was no sum of the variable `célula`. What can I do to get a "return" from A1 and A2?

```
import xlwings as xw

wb = xw.Book(r'C:\Users\Guilh\bin\teste\Contabilização Automática\myproject\myproject.xlsx')

sht = wb.sheets[0]

def buscar():

    linha = '1'
    célula = 'A' + linha
    valor_célula = sht.range(célula).value

    while valor_célula != None:
        print('A1')

        linha = int(linha) + 1
        célula = 'A' + str(linha)

    else:
        print('A2')
```

Comment: change `while` with `if`?

Comment: `valor_célula` is only calculated once, before the loop, so `while valor_célula != None:` is _forever_ true once you enter that loop. You need to recalculate `valor_célula` inside the `while` loop so that its value might change

Comment: Perfect, @roganjosh!!! Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have neglected to update `valor_célula` and thus are stuck in the while loop.

I believe you want to update your code to be:

```
def buscar():

    linha = '1'
    célula = 'A' + linha
    valor_célula = sht.range(célula).value

    while valor_célula != None:
        print('A1')

        linha = int(linha) + 1
        célula = 'A' + str(linha)
        valor_célula = sht.range(célula).value  # Update Value

    else:
        print('A2')
```